# Set cookie without page refresh

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, cookies

I am showing a jQuery overlay when users first visit a particular page

They have a radio button in the overlay that they can click to say they do not wish to see the notification again

I want to set a cookie that the user doesnt want to see the overlay again

Is it possible to set the cookie without refreshing the page?

I was going to make a ajax call back to the server and then set the cookie in the response headers but I guess they wont get set in an Ajax request/response?

Is it safe / OK to set the cookie purely from javascript? Or is that a bad idea?

any other options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason that an AJAX call cannot set a cookie. It is basically just an HTTP request.

[AJAX Requests Get And Set Cookies Like Any Other HTTP Request](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1995-AJAX-Requests-Get-And-Set-Cookies-Like-Any-Other-HTTP-Request.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You may use [jQuery Cookie Plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie).

Some example:

```
function setCookieFilters() {
    var $filtersContent = $(".dynamic-filters");
    if ($filtersContent.length > 0) {
        if ($filtersContent.css("display") == "none") {
            $.cookie("isUsingFilters", "true", { expires: 7 });
        }
        else {
            $.cookie("isUsingFilters", "false", { expires: 7 });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could also just get/set the cookie in plain old javascript:
[Create and Store a Cookie](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)

Comment: sure - I appreciate that. Just wasn't sure how good an idea that was. I usually set cookies from server side code and was a bit unsure of whether doing it from javascript is a solid solution.

Answer (score -1):

Use this: this shall reload the page.

```
setcookie($data,$item_data, time()+ (3600));
echo "<script>location.href='index.php'</script>;
```

Comment: This is exactly the opposite of what the question is!