# Cookie in Set-Cookie header not being set

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cookies, axios, cross-domain

I'm sending a request to a node.js server from a reactjs client using axios as shown below.

```
import axios from 'axios';

const apiClient = axios.create({
  withCredentials: true,
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:8080'
});

async function(payload) {
  try {
    debugger;
    let result = await apiClient.post('/auth/signup/', payload);
    debugger;
    return result;
  } catch (error) {
    debugger;
    throw error;
  }
}
```

The node.js endpoint sets a cookie in the response as shown below.

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
const cors = require('cors');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

router.use(bodyParser.json());
router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
router.use(cors({ origin: 'http://localhost:3000', credentials: true, exposedHeaders: ['Set-Cookie', 'Date', 'ETag']} ));
router.use(cookieParser());


router.post('/signup', async (req, res, next) => {
  debugger;
  let database = req.app.locals.database;
  try {
    let user = await database.findByUsername(req.body.username);
    let token = await jwt.sign({username: user.username}, config.secret, {expiresIn: "15m"});
    res.cookie('jwt',  token, {
      maxAge: 900,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    debugger;
    return res.status(503).send({ auth: false, message: 'Database error.' });
  }
});
```

The Set-Cookie header of the response contains the cookie as expected.

[image: Set-Cookie Header]

However, Chrome does not appear to be setting the cookie, as I cannot see the cookie in the Application window of the Developer Console.

[image: Cookies]

I've looked at the answers to the following questions, which mention setting `{ withCredentials: true }` in the axios configuration and not using a wildcard origin for cors in node.js, but I am already doing both.

[Set-Cookie header not setting cookie in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31058542/set-cookie-header-not-setting-cookie-in-chrome)

[Set cookies for cross origin requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46288437/set-cookies-for-cross-origin-requests)

Any ideas as to why the cookie is not being set and how to fix this issue?

Comment: Good question. Inserting images into it, upvoting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Though you are hosting client and server in the same domain as `http://localhost`, your ports are different, so the same-origin policy is failed here. You can check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy.

As so, you making a CORS request, check your network tab in your developer tools in your current browser, you might see a preflight request `OPTIONS`, before your client sends `POST` request to your server.

The server must specify headers to accept the origin of your next request - POST request from `http://localhost:8000` with method `POST`, you can refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request

```
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST // Your next request will use POST method
Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true // cookies accepted
```

Added:

In `Set-Cookie`, `Max-Age` must be [non-zero digit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie). It be rounded up into integer according to [RFC doc](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-5.2.2). For express.js, cookies `maxAge property is on the scale of [miliseconds](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.cookie)

The solution will be set the `maxAge` property as `second * 1000`

```js
    res.cookie('jwt',  token, {
      maxAge: 10000,
    });
```

Comment: Just check the cors middleware of express. It seems to do all the work for setting CORS config in the pre-flight response. Now, I'm very interested in what the response will look like.

Comment: Preflight requests can no longer be viewed in Chrome DevTools according to this source: https://httptoolkit.tech/blog/chrome-79-doesnt-show-cors-preflight. I am also not quite sure what exactly you are saying I should be looking for in the preflight request / response. Could you please clarify?

Comment: From the screen, it looks like you have no problem with the values of HTTP cookies being responded by the server. Then, check the `Max-Age` in your `Set-Cookie`, it might be the problem, as IIRC that value must be non-zero digit.

Comment: Thank you, a `Max-Age` value of 0 was indeed the issue. I thought I was setting the `Max-Age` with `res.cookie('jwt',  token, {maxAge: 900});` in node, but looking at the `Set-Cookie` header, the `Max-Age` was 0. Although the `maxAge` property in the cookie options in node is in milliseconds, the `Max-Age` in the `Set-Cookie` header is in seconds, so my value of 900 milliseconds was being rounded down to 0 seconds. Add the information in your comment to your answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a repost of my answer on a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/a/62821342/8479303

---

In my case, the network panel showed that the response had the 'Set-Cookie' header, but in axios the header wouldn't show up, and the cookie was being set.

For me, the resolution was setting the `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` header.

For explanation, from [this comment](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/2847#issuecomment-605417894) on an issue in the axios repository I was directed to this [person's notes](https://github.com/chinesedfan/You-Dont-Know-Axios#nightmares-of-headers-cors-cookies-and-auth) which led me to set the [`Access-Control-Expose-Headers` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Access-Control-Expose-Headers) -- and now the cookie is properly setting in the client.

So, in Express.js, I had to add the `exposedHeaders` option to my cors middleware:

```
const corsOptions = {
  //To allow requests from client
  origin: [
    "http://localhost:3001",
    "http://127.0.0.1",
    "http://104.142.122.231",
  ],
  credentials: true,
  exposedHeaders: ["set-cookie"],
};

...

app.use("/", cors(corsOptions), router);
```

---

It was also important that on the axios side I use the `withCredentials` config in following axios requests that I wanted to include the cookies.

ex/

```
const { data } = await api.get("/workouts", { withCredentials: true });
```

Comment: exposedHeaders: ["set-cookie"] seems to be critical when using Axios on the front end

Answer (score 0):

If anyone having the same problem, this might help.

Frontend: If using axios then add: `withCredentials: true.` For fetch() add: `credentials: 'include'`.

Backend: If you're on `http://localhost:....` then you could add to your cookie `sameSite:'lax'`, just make sure you're not adding `Secure` to this cookie while you on `http://localhost` because it is only for `https` not `http`, else your cookie won't be added to the browser. While in production adding `sameSite: 'none'` and `Secure` is ok.

I've added some headers too:

```
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers','Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, authorization')
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','http://localhost:3000');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-METHODS',"GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE, OPTIONS, PATCH");
```

Also added:

```
app.use(cors({
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
    credentials: true
}))
```

Just make sure you're not using `'*'` when adding your origin in headers or cors. Write as shown in an example above : `origin: 'http://localhost:3000'` and `res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','http://localhost:3000');`

All of the above helped me with my project, I hope it will help someone else too.